# Deleting a Row in R based on value in column

Tags: r

Have a dataframe in R, I want to delete all rows in that dataframe where column X has values >100%. Whats the best way to do this?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Values greater than 100% of what?

Comment: The column just contains % values e.g. 10%,12%,100%,1200% - I want to get rid of all rows where this column has anything >100% as its not relevant to my analysis. Thanks

Comment: See help(subset). In fact, see any basic R help document which will tell you how to do this on about page 3.

Answer (score 11):

If your column `X` contains numbers (which I'm pretty sure it does although your use of % symbols gives bit different impression), then you can select the rows `i` where `X[i]<100` like this:

```
 datasetnew <- dataset[dataset$X<=100,]
```

But if you really have percentages in the column, i.e. values in `X` are something like `"10%","23%","103%"`, then you need to remove the `%` first, for example using the `gsub` function:

```
datasetnew <- dataset[as.numeric(gsub(dataset$X,"%",""))<=100,]
```